# Finding matches amongst multiple javascript arrays and output the repeating array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I just want to find matches between multiple arrays based on first value in an array and keep the matching results.

```
[
    [[11,1], [22,2], [33,3]],
    [[11,1], [10,1], [22,1]],
    [[11,10], [12,1], [22,1]]
]
```

Above is my sample array. first unique values in those arrays are `11, 22, 33, 10, 12` so out of which `11, 22` are repeated across all the three arrays.

And would like to to produce the following array that contains matches from all given arrays:

```
[
    [[11,1], [22,2]],
    [[11,1], [22,1]],
    [[11,10], [22,1]]
]
```

I just tried with javascript reduce function, but couldn't solve it and not getting the result as expected.

Comment: Throw your reduce function in a separate block as well. People want to see what you did otherwise you could say you parsed it using the most advanced IA in the world...but I'm no believer. Also do you want the original array modified or do you want a new array?

Answer (score 3):

You could filter first for common values and map the result with the filtered arrays.

```js
const
    data = [
        [[11, 1], [22, 2], [33, 3]],
        [[11, 1], [10, 1], [22, 1]],
        [[11, 10], [12, 1], [22, 1]]
    ],
    common = data.reduce((a, b) => a.filter(([v]) => b.some(([w]) => v === w))),
    result = data.map(a => a.filter(([v]) => common.some(([w]) => v === w)));

console.log(common);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

First build an `track` object to have numbers and count of occurrences. 
Then, `filter` the `data` whether first number is repeated or not.

```js
const data = [
    [[11,1], [22,2], [33,3]],
    [[11,1], [10,1], [22,1]],
    [[11,10], [12,1], [22,1]]
];

const track = {};
data.flat().forEach(([num]) => track[num] = (track[num] ?? -1) + 1)

const new_data = data.map(arr => arr.filter(([num]) => track[num]))

console.log(new_data)
```